# Virtualenv OSError setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 127

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I can't install **virtualenv** on u**buntu 16.04 /python3.6**

I'm running `virtualenv -p python3 .`

There is some threads about similar errors but I couldn't find the solution.

Can anyone help me?

```
OSError: Command /home/rony/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 127
```

Thanks.

Comment: What command have you run? It should be `python3 -m pip install -U setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel`

Comment: I'm running `virtualenv -p python3 .`